# How do I enable jetty-maven-plugin 8 server debug output?

Tags: maven, slf4j, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade our jetty from 7 to 8 so that we can take advantage of servlet 3.0.  It doesn't appear that any settings or configuration changes were made from 7 to 8.  Previously we've been using jetty-maven-plugin 7.2.0.RC0 to mvn jetty:run (along with catalina 6.0.29, slf4j 1.5.9 and servlet 2.5).  When updating jetty, I had to add in the slf4j, log4j and javax.servlet-api dependencies to the plugin so that there wouldn't be API problems.  The catalina dependency has always been there.  Here's the pom now:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.10.v20130312</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.37</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <webAppConfig>
        <contextPath>/widgets</contextPath>
        <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
          <resourcesAsCSV>/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/src/main/webapp,/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/target/neo-js</resourcesAsCSV>
        </baseResource>
        <overrideDescriptor>/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/target/generated-resources/xml/override-web-default.xml</overrideDescriptor>
      </webAppConfig>
      <contextHandlers>
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <war>/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/target/dependency-wars/neo.war</war>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          <tempDirectory>/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/target/tmp-neo</tempDirectory>
        </contextHandler>
      </contextHandlers>
      <scanTargets>
        <scanTarget>src/main/resources</scanTarget>
        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp</scanTarget>
      </scanTargets>
      <jettyConfig>/Users/dwinsor/neo/neo-js/target/generated-resources/xml/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        </connector>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
        </connector>
      </connectors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

My problem is that I'm no longer seeing the kind of debug output that I expect to see.  In jetty 7 when I did mvn jetty:run I'd see something like

> org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer@271bc503 STOPPED
>   +-SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
>   +-SslSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8443
>   +-qtp62871287{8<=5<=8/254,0}
>   +-HandlerCollection@c237b89 started
>      +-ContextHandlerCollection@6d836598 started
>      | +-JettyWebAppContext@17043b2f@17043b2f/widgets,[file:/Users/dwinsor/previ
>   ...
>   ...
>   [INFO] Started Jetty Server

Now, however, all I see is the last line, [INFO] Started Jetty Server.
I want to be able to see all the pretty WebAppContext output.  I've tried -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.DEBUG=true and -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG, yet we weren't using either of these before anyways.  How can I enable this output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at jetty 7.3.0 the debug output seen is no longer printed out unless certain properties were set in jetty.xml:

`<Set name="dumpAfterStart">true</Set>`

`<Set name="dumpBeforeStop">true</Set>`